# NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I am doing the following code to send dictionary from one viewcontroller to another after adding data to the dictionary from my end too.

```
 else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
        NSString *identifier=segue.identifier;
        NSIndexPath *index = [self.listTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSMutableDictionary *selectedDic;
        selectedDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        selectedDic= [dataArray objectAtIndex:index.row];
        [selectedDic setObject:@"abc" forKey:@"UserID"];
        detailViewController.tripDetails =[selectedDic mutableCopy];
         detailViewController.identifier = identifier;
    }
```

but it shows the above exception.What does it mean and how it can be fixed?

Comment: The row `selectedDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];` is completely needless.

Comment: dataArray must be containing  NSDictionary and you are trying to setObject in NSDictionary thats the reason for crash. Add NSMutableDictionary type object in your dataArray and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you are trying to change a dictionary that is not mutable. You initialized selectedDic as an NSMutableDictionary which is good but then you reassign it to be [dataArray objectAtIndex:index.row]. You didn't post enough information to be able for me to determine what's in dataArray but assuming that the dataArray is an array of NSDictionaries, you can make this work by changing that line to [[dataArray objectAtIndex:index.row] mutableCopy]. If that dataArray is not an array of dictionaries then you might need to rethink what you are trying to do.